# How to post variables with jquery.post

Tags: jquery

I want to post 3 variables.  Request,Arival,Departure.   It must be somewhere in the script. I tried different ways but can't get it working

```
  Request = '{REQUEST}',
  Arrival = '{ARRIVAL}',
  Departure = '{DEPARTURE}'
```

My script is:

```
<script>

   jQuery().ready(function(){
     setInterval("getResult()",1000); 
 });

   function getResult(){   
     jQuery.post("search.php", function( data ) {
     jQuery("#show").html(data);
 });
}
</script>

<button onclick="getResult()" >Get result</button>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: How have you tried posting the variables? I don't see the different ways you tried in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post( "search.php", {string: string, name: name}, function( data ) {
  $( "#show" ).html( data );
});
```

best reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You should read some documentation and try something out before you ask something in StakOverflow.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the script working, but when i renew the variables notting happens.The values of variables don't renew.

```
  <script>
  function getResult()
  {   
  jQuery.post( "search.php", { request: '{REQUEST}', arrival: '{ARRIVAL}', departure: '{DEPARTURE}' })
  .done(function( data ) {
  jQuery("#show").html(data);

      });
  }
  </script>

  <button onclick="getResult()" >Get result</button>
  <div id="show"></div>
```